# The returned data is of type "Promise {<Fulfilled>: Array(1)}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, promise

Can someone help me understand why this piece of code is not working?

```js
const handleFetchPrices = async () => {
    // Do a fetch per item to get prices for the entire shoppingList.
    const promises = shoppingList.map(item => {
      return fetch(`https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=${item.typeid}${jita}`)
        .then(response => {
          let completeItem = {
            data: response.json(),
            name: item.name,
            amount: item.amount,
          }
          return completeItem
        })
    })
    // When all fetches are complete, setFetchedItems is called
    Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
      const returnedItems = results.map(result => console.log(result))
      //console.log("Returned items: ", results)
      setFetchedItems(returnedItems)
    })
  }
```

After this is executed i try to access the returnedItem.data, but it seems that the promise was never resolved. Any tips on how to fix this?

I honestly could not find a solution i understood, and am at my wits end on how to resolve these promises properly.

Comment: I think you need to return fetch without `.then()` and map result into `promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `.then` on `response.json`

```js
const handleFetchPrices = async() => {
  // Do a fetch per item to get prices for the entire shoppingList.
  const promises = shoppingList.map(item => {
    return fetch(`https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=${item.typeid}${jita}`)
      .then(response => {
        return response.json().then(data => {
          let completeItem = {
            data,
            name: item.name,
            amount: item.amount,
          }
          return completeItem
        })
      })
  })
  // When all fetches are complete, setFetchedItems is called
  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    const returnedItems = results.map(result => console.log(result))
    //console.log("Returned items: ", results)
    setFetchedItems(returnedItems)
  })
}
```

Or use `await` instead

```js
const handleFetchPrices = async() => {
  // Do a fetch per item to get prices for the entire shoppingList.
  const promises = shoppingList.map(async item => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.evemarketer.com/ec/marketstat/json?typeid=${item.typeid}${jita}`)
    const data = await response.json()
    let completeItem = {
      data,
      name: item.name,
      amount: item.amount,
    }
    return completeItem
  })
  // When all fetches are complete, setFetchedItems is called
  Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    const returnedItems = results.map(result => console.log(result))
    //console.log("Returned items: ", results)
    setFetchedItems(returnedItems)
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, have been trying to figure this out for weeks to no avail. I see i still need a ton of practice with promises...